# How to send packets larger than 1500 bytes by pcap_sendpacket?

Tags: networking, network-programming, pcap, ethernet

Actually, I have two related questions.

I'm capturing filtered network traffic by [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) on Debian. Then I need to replay this traffic on Win2k3 server. Sometimes I capture packets, both TCP and UDP, much larger than 1500 bytes (default MTU size for Ethernet). E.g., 2000+ bytes. I did no specific changes to MTU size on that Linux. So question #1:

**What's the reason for these packets much larger than default MTU?** [Jumbo frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_Frames)? This Wikipedia article states that "network interface cards capable of jumbo frames require explicit configuration to use jumbo frames", but I'm not aware about any such configuration. Also `ifconfig` shows me "MTU:1500". Can it be somehow related with "interrupt-combining" technique (or "interrupt coalescing" as in [this article](http://www.evanjones.ca/ethernet-latency.html))? Can I supress such packets?

Then, question #2:

**How can I send such packets by `pcap_sendpacket` on Windows?** I receive error message "send error: PacketSendPacket failed" only for packets larger than 1500 bytes. Seems I cannot use jumbo frames because I'm sending data to directly connected custom "net tap" like pci card  and I'm not sure I can configure its NIC. What else? Should I fragment these packets according to the protocol rules?

**EDIT:**

Checked fragmentation by NIC as Guy Harris suggested:

```
~# ethtool -k eth0
Offload parameters for eth0:
rx-checksumming: on
tx-checksumming: on
scatter-gather: on
tcp-segmentation-offload: off
udp-fragmentation-offload: off
generic-segmentation-offload: off
generic-receive-offload: off
large-receive-offload: off
ntuple-filters: off
receive-hashing: off
```

The same for `eth1` and `br0` - network bridge between `eth0` and `eth1` which I'm sniffing.

And I still receive large UDP packets.

Comment: pcap is probably gluing fragmented datagrams back together into one chunk from the wire packets for you. Check if you can ask it to give you ethernet frames and not transport packets.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov: I'm receiving ethernet frames

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¿Are you using the wireshark to capture?

It's important beacause by default wireshark reassemble fragmented ip datagrams (and stores them in a pcap file as reassembled MTU-higger single packages without fragmentation).
To disable:

Edit->preferences->Protocols->ipV4-> and uncheck "Reassemble fragmented IPv4 datagrams".

Comment: I'm capturing by libpcap (the core of Wireshark). Any info how to disable this in libpcap?

Comment: Libpcap hasn't this feature by itself unless the package you use has applied this patch -> http://seclists.org/tcpdump/2007/q2/112 You can check your version of libpcap or download the official one instead of using the one provided by the distribution (sometimes they apply weird patches...)

Comment: +1. tnx for the info, I built the last libpcap from sources, now I see only a bit bigger packets than MTU, 1518 bytes. Seems because of Ethernet trailer. But I still cannot send these packets by `pcap_sendpacket`. Should I modify them by removing that trailer?

Comment: It's ok. I'd need something bigger to explain :). It's not the Ethernet trailer, it only appears when the packet is smaller than 64 bytes (for example ARP) and since the ethernet frame minimun size it's 64 it fills the rest of the packet with the trailer (but only when the packet is smaller). But, obviously this is not your case, the 18 extra bytes it's not the padding. The MTU it's not an ethernet maximun frame, it's the DATAGRAM maximun size [http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/nov/5/mtu-manipulation/].

Comment: [COMES FROM LAST COMMENT] So in the framented packages, if there is an MTU of 1500 (1460 payload + 20 TCP hdr + 20 IP hdr ) you must plus the 14 bytes of the Ethernet header or 18 if you have VLAN (802.1Q) in your ethernet frames = 1518 bytes. This is why you have this kind of packages. The problem of pcap_sendpacket... :) it could be a bug in maximun size calculation (ethernet header size should not be taken in consideration).

Answer (score 7):

Your network adapter is probably doing TCP segmentation/desegmentation offloading and IP fragmentation/reassembly offloading, so:

- UDP packets being sent by your machine that are larger than will fit in a single Ethernet frame are being handed to the network adapter without being fragmented, with the network adapter doing the fragmentation, and those are also handed to libpcap before being fragmented;
- UDP fragments being received by your network adapter that are larger than will fit in a single Ethernet frame are being reassembled by the network adapter before being handed to the host, and are being handed to libpcap after being reassembled;
- chunks of TCP stream data being sent by your machine that are too big to fit in a single Ethernet frame are being handed to the network adapter, with the network adapter breaking the chunks up into smaller TCP segments, and the full chunk is being handed to libpcap;
- TCP segments received by your network adapter are being reassembled into larger chunks of TCP data and the chunks are being handed to the host and then to libpcap;

so what libpcap is seeing are *not* Ethernet packets and are *not* limited to the Ethernet frame size.

(I.e., Nikolai Fetissov was probably correct; what you're receiving might *look like* Ethernet frames, but that's because the network adapter and driver make them look that way.  They are, in fact, not Ethernet frames transmitted on or received from the Ethernet.)

You can only suppress them by turning off whatever form of segmentation/desegmentation/fragmentation/reassembly is being done on your network adapter using the `ethtool` command; turn off options such as TCP Segementation Offload, UDP Fragmentation Offload, General Segmentation Offload, Large Receive Offload, and Generic Receive Offload.

Once you've disabled those options, you should no longer have those large packets, and thus you should be able to replay them with no problem.  There *is* no easy way to replay the reassembled/un-fragmented-or-segmented packets you've captured so far - you'd have to write your own code to fragment them, and there's no guarantee that they'd be re-fragmented/re-segmented in the same way that they were originally fragmented/segmented on the wire.